# Is it possible to pre-define the content blocks for an area in Concrete5 CMS?

Tags: html, content-management-system, block, concrete5

I'm using Concrete5 CMS for a client project of mine but have the problem that (ideally) I'd like to be able to nest HTML structures in such a way that the content editor will be able to edit the site without having to know or write any HTML. An example structure is...

```
<header class="page-header"><!-- Defined as a GlobalArea -->

    <div class="site-meta"><!-- Defined as a Block Group (Stack?) -->
        <p class="contact-info"><!-- Defined as a Block -->
            <!-- User editable content -->
        </p>
        ....other content...
    </div>

    <div class="branding"><!-- Defined as a Block group -->
        <div class="logo"><!-- Defined as a Block -->
            <!-- User editable content -->
        </div>

        <hgroup><!-- Custom wrapper of sub-blocks -->
            <h1 class="brandname"><!-- Defined as a Block -->
                <!-- User editable content -->
            </h1>

            <h2 class="tagline"><!-- Defined as a Block -->
                <!-- User editable content -->
            </h2>
        </hgroup>
    </div>

    <p class="description"><!-- Defined as a Block -->
        <!-- User editable content -->
    </p>
</header>
```

As you can see I need separate user editable content "Blocks" grouped in to larger 'meta' blocks within a defined content "Area" (or grouped areas). Although it's my understanding that Concrete5 is not capable of functioning in this way -- i.e. Areas cannot contain other Areas and Blocks cannot contain other Blocks.

In which case I was wondering how it would be possible to manually load a specific content Block from the database using just the raw php code. This way I hope to be able to pre-define the content blocks for a given area and hopefully forcibly insert a block within a specific structure of HTML.

Thanks for any and all help people can offer me.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I grasp your question - you are not talking about *nested* areas, but just multiple ones per page, correct? What you show in your HTML is definitely possible, but what you say you want in your text is not

Comment: Sorry Pekka, I have edited my example to (hopefully) be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the free Designer Content add-on... you can create custom blocks that have markup embedded in it.  This will get you most of the way to the markup you are looking to create. If necessary, you can use the block code it creates and customize your custom block more precisely.

http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/designer-content/

Comment: Thanks, I am already using the Designer Content add on ;)  -- I guess it will have to do for now. TBH I'm amazed that the team behind C5 haven't built it to be capable of nested content from the start, after all HTML is a nested language (Doh!).

Comment: Yeah, I see your point... on the other hand, I think they've provided us with several good options... and the degree of technical requirement depends on how repeatable you need it to be within a page.

Comment: For instance, if the user-editable regions don't need to be repeated, you can define all of these elements in your page template, and then define the block type default in the page template settings.  But if you want the user to be able to add a bunch of block elements on the fly, then you have the Designer Content add-on and ultimately the block creation framework... in any case, I think the framework is extremely flexible, which is great.

Comment: I think the underlying architecture of C5 revolves around blocks on a page, so that is always the preferred solution (as far as the core team is concerned). But of course there are situations where you just want some repeating data in one block. I have a long-term project I'm working on where I hope to provide that functionality, because you are not the only one who has this problem. Can't say when that will be done though (probably not for a while).

Answer (score 2):

Is there really a business need for the upper level area groups with nested areas? This is typically handled by the template. For example:

```
<header class="page-header">

    <div class="site-meta">
        <p class="contact-info">
           <?php
                $a = new Area('Contact Info');
                $a->display($c);
            ?>
        </p>
        <!-- ....other content... -->
    </div>

    <div class="branding">
        <div class="logo">
            <?php
                $a = new Area('Logo');
                $a->display($c);
            ?>
        </div>

        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="brandname">
                <?php
                    $a = new Area('Brand Name');
                    $a->display($c);
                ?>
            </h1>

            <h2 class="tagline">
                <?php
                    $a = new Area('Tag Line');
                    $a->display($c);
                ?>
            </h2>
        </hgroup>
    </div>

    <p class="description">
        <?php
            $a = new Area('Description');
            $a->display($c);
        ?>
    </p>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks BrianJM, you probably right perhaps I am being a bit too pedantic and not objective enough. I did start out working with it this way, perhaps I should go back to it.

Comment: @Chris I think you are confusing areas with blocks and the intended functionality of each. Areas, as defined in the code above, contain blocks. You cannot have areas contained within areas, nor can blocks contain blocks. Areas can contain multiple blocks. Typically, multiple templates are setup when the area requirements change. Hope this helps.